# Does extending a base class multiple times uses more memory than a single instance of that class?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering about the best practice to create an efficient web app. which one of this implementations is more efficient and which one is better in large scale applications?

Every class extends the base request class and has access to request methods:

```js
class BaseRequestClass {
  get(url) {
    return Promise.resolve() // Some api request
  }
}

class Users extends BaseRequestClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.users = []
  }
}

class Admins extends BaseRequestClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.admins = []
  }
}

const users = new Users();
const admins = new Admins();
users.get('users').then((response) => users.users = response)
admins.get('admins').then((response) => admins.admins = response)
```

or creating a single instance of `BaseRequestClass` and use it every time that we want to make a request like this one:

```js
class BaseRequestClass {
  get(url) {
    return Promise.resolve() // Some api request
  }
}

class Users {
  constructor() {
    this.users = []
  }
}

class Admins {
  constructor() {
    this.admins = []
  }
}
const request = new BaseRequestClass()
const users = new Users();
const admins = new Admins();
request.get('users').then((response) => users.users = response)
request.get('admins').then((response) => admins.admins = response)
```

Comment: Yes, it does (at least when creating the classes), but the difference is negligible, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @Teemu I have really big list of this kind of class objects that uses a lot of memory and of course they are not this simple. I wondered if extending this base class causes more memory usage than simply create an instance of it and use it whenever it is needed.

Comment: Storing classes takes some memory of course. Keeping up a prototype chain itself doesn't consume memory, instead it makes referring a property, lying deep in the chain, a bit slower. But if there are some combinations you'll never need, then it might be better not to create such a chain. Ex. you'll need an instance of D, which of prototype chain is D -> C -> B -> A, but you'll never need an instance or prototype of B -> A, then you can combine A and B into the same class AB, and the chain would be D -> C -> AB.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the first approach, though I would house the specific to each Class within the class instead of passing in as a param.

```
class BaseRequestClass {
  get(url) {
    return Promise.resolve() // Some api request, using this.resource
  }
}

class Users extends BaseRequestClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.resource = 'users' // <!-- here
    this.users = []
  }

  getAll(){
     ...
  }
}
```

meaning the usage becomes -

```
users.getAll()
```

etc

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. this approach is really neat but is it memory efficient in case of big list of this `Users` class that repeatedly extends that `BaseRequestClass` ? how javascript handles memory in this situation ?

Comment: if you're worried about the size of the user array, you'll need to paginate the results from the API